# DOORS DXL: Unable to operate against global button // toggling control active/inactive

Tags: function, ibm-doors

Alright, so, I found the helpful answer as to how to enable/disable (active/inactive) a control using DXL, but now I feel I have a problem that I don't understand, somehow relative to the order in which the functions are loaded.

Problem: When I create a dialog, I have two buttons, one button is inactive shortly after being created.  When I press Button 1, I want to force Button 2 to become active, but instead, I get an error stating that Button 2 is unassigned, which is strange because it was declared globally and setup in the main function.  So, what am I doing wrong??

Here is my code...

```
pragma runLim,10000

DB main_dialog = null
DBE main_button1 = null
DBE main_button2 = null

void toggle_visibility_other_button(DBE dbe)
{
    active(main_button2)
}

void do_something(DBE dbe)
{
    infoBox "UNDER CONSTRUCTION"
}

void main_function()
{   
    main_dialog = create("My GUI", styleCentered)
    main_button1 = button(main_dialog, "Button 1", toggle_visibility_other_button)
    main_button2 = button(main_dialog, "Button 2", do_something)

    inactive(main_button2)

    realize(main_dialog)
    setSize(main_dialog, 300, 150)
}

main_function
```

Comment: Hey @TheKirkwoods, if you feel the Russel has answered the question, you can mark it as accepted. This lets others know that it fixes the issue, likewise it's useful to know if it doesn't work so that we can try to help more

Answer (score 1):

Okay!

This is a pretty simple issue, but I'm going to take a second to explain what's happening.

In DOORS, there are 2 ways to finalize a Dialog Box and display it to the user:

```
show(DB box)
```

or

```
block(DB box)
```

The first one displays the dialog box, but the rest of the DOORS interface is still 'live'. No code after a 'show' will be executed- everything has to be in callbacks built into the dialog box.

The second one displays the dialog box, but freezes the rest of the DOORS interface until the dialog box is closed or the release function is called. Once you close the dialog box, the DXL program will continue.

Now, in your program, you used the 'realize' command. This is used to basically configure the dialog box visuals, but doesn't actually set up the buttons and sub functions properly. Then your setSize came along and set the dialog box to be displayed, but you still need a show- see the following.

```
//Show example
pragma runLim,10000

DB main_dialog = null
DBE main_button1 = null
DBE main_button2 = null

void toggle_visibility_other_button(DBE dbe)
{
    active(main_button2)
}

void do_something(DBE dbe)
{
    infoBox "UNDER CONSTRUCTION"
}

void main_function()
{   
    main_dialog = create("My GUI", styleCentered)
    main_button1 = button(main_dialog, "Button 1", toggle_visibility_other_button)
    main_button2 = button(main_dialog, "Button 2", do_something)

    inactive(main_button2)

    realize(main_dialog)
    setSize(main_dialog, 300, 150)
    // Added This
    show(main_dialog)
    print "Ran it!"
}

main_function
```

And the block example:

```
//block example
pragma runLim,10000

DB main_dialog = null
DBE main_button1 = null
DBE main_button2 = null

void toggle_visibility_other_button(DBE dbe)
{
    active(main_button2)
}

void do_something(DBE dbe)
{
    infoBox "UNDER CONSTRUCTION"
}

void main_function()
{   
    main_dialog = create("My GUI", styleCentered)
    main_button1 = button(main_dialog, "Button 1", toggle_visibility_other_button)
    main_button2 = button(main_dialog, "Button 2", do_something)

    inactive(main_button2)

    realize(main_dialog)
    setSize(main_dialog, 300, 150)
    // Added This
    block(main_dialog)
    print "Ran it!"
}

main_function
```

There are some DOORS functions that will require you to have done a realize() in order to configure your Dialog Box Elements (prior to the call to show() or block())- an example would be adding columns to a listview DBE. I'm not sure I've ever seen a comprehensive list of these situations anywhere.

Let me know if this helps!